# Add layouts to my tabs?

Tags: android, layout, tabs, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I was following this turtorial: [Implement Tabhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17687717/tutorial-to-implement-the-use-of-tabhost-in-android-2-2-viewpager-and-fragment)

And got stuck on adding some layouts to my tabs and had no clue how to add them.
Here is the code for adding some content to the tabs but i can just add strings.

```
private List<Fragment> getFragments(){
    List<Fragment> fList = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
    // TODO (ADD LAYOUTS)

    MySampleFragment f1 = MySampleFragment.newInstance("");
    MySampleFragment f2 = MySampleFragment.newInstance("");
    MySampleFragment f3 = MySampleFragment.newInstance("24");
    fList.add(f1);
    fList.add(f2);
    fList.add(f3);

    return fList;
}
```

And here is the MySampleFragment.class

```
package com.example.soundboard;

  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
  import android.view.LayoutInflater;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.view.ViewGroup;
  import android.widget.TextView;
  import com.example.soundboard.R;

public class MySampleFragment extends Fragment {
private static View mView;

public static final MySampleFragment newInstance(String sampleText) {
    MySampleFragment f = new MySampleFragment();

    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putString("bString", sampleText);
    f.setArguments(b);

    return f;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
    String sampleText = getArguments().getString("bString");

    TextView txtSampleText = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.txtViewSample);
    txtSampleText.setText(sampleText);

    return mView;
}
}
```

Is there someway to add a layout instead of writing strings in the tabs?

Answer (score 0):

You are passing strings in constructor -> then as arguments in following code

```
MySampleFragment f1 = MySampleFragment.newInstance("");
MySampleFragment f2 = MySampleFragment.newInstance("");
MySampleFragment f3 = MySampleFragment.newInstance("24");
```

Inside the fragment you are retrieving like this.

```
String sampleText = getArguments().getString("bString");
```

Now you can load different layouts based on string.. like this

```
if(sampleText.equalsIgnoreCase("Layout1") {
    mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false); //R.layout.fragment is the layout you are loading
}
else if // some other condition 
    mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment2, container, false); //R.layout.fragment2 is the layout you are loading
```

`R.layout.fragment` etc are the xml layout you create inside res->layout folder of your project