# ViewPager in DialogFragment - IllegalStateException: Fragment does not have a view

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-dialogfragment

### What I want to achieve

- From a `FragmentActivity` show a dialog when clicking an Action Button in the Action Bar
- `DialogFragment` - A Dialog without title
- `TabHost` - Tabs at the top of the dialog
- `ViewPager` with `FragmentPagerAdapter` - Swipable, which content is connected to the Tabs
- 2-3 Dialog Buttons (different subclasses of the Dialog, different buttons) - Are not supposed to be in one of the `ViewPager`'s `Fragment`, meaning the same buttons should remain at the bottom of the Dialog regardless of what `Fragment` the `ViewPager` is showing.

### The problem

```
IllegalStateException: Fragment does not have a view
```

### What I have tried/done so far

- Using the `android.support.v4` package for necessary classes
- Calling `getChildFragmentManager()` instead of `getSupportedFragmentManager()`
- Implemented what post #10 suggested from this link **https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=42601**. I copy/paste the code directly into my two `Fragment` classes, which the `ViewPager` is suppose to be showing, plus the `DialogFragment` class.
- In my custom `DialogFragment` I first tried to override `onCreateView`, then `onCreateDialog` and then both at the same time. All of which I got to run but with unexpected results.

  - Only `onCreateView`: Can't reach the `AlertDialog.Builder` to create the needed buttons, other than that the Dialog's results were great.
  - Only `onCreateDialog`: the error message shown above. I still imagine this method to be as close as I've gotten to what I want to achieve.
  - Both `onCreateView` and `onCreateDialog`: Inflated the Dialog layout in `onCreateView` and added the Dialog buttons to the `AlertDialog.Builder` in `onCreateDialog`. This displayed the dialog, but the added buttons from the `AlertDialog.Builder` were not visable. Plus the keyboard didn't show up when clicking on a `EditText` field.

### Source code

Most come from **[Tutorial to implement the use of TabHost in Android 2.2 + ViewPager and Fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17687717/tutorial-to-implement-the-use-of-tabhost-in-android-2-2-viewpager-and-fragment)**. The code of the `ActivityFragment` is instead in a `DialogFragment`. However I replaced its ViewPager with a modified one from the source code from this answer **https://stackoverflow.com/a/18167273/2375978**. This was to be able to `wrap_content` on height.

The faulty code in my project is in `DialogFragment`'s `onCreateDialog` method, I believe.

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity(), AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_DARK);
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_test, null);
    addActionButtons(builder, view);    
    builder.setView(view);

    mViewPager = (WrapContentHeightViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

    initialiseTabHost();

    List<Fragment> fragments = getFragments();

    pageAdapter = new DialogPageAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), fragments);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(pageAdapter);
    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);

    Dialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
    dialog.show();

    return dialog;
}
```

### Stack trace LogCat log

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment does not have a view
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment$1.findViewById(Fragment.java:1425)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:901)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1088)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1444)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:461)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1011)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:880)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1374)
    at my.app.package.name.WrapContentHeightViewPager.onMeasure(WrapContentHeightViewPager.java:31)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15481)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5059)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1396)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:681)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15481)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5059)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15481)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:617)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:399)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15481)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5059)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15481)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5059)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15481)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5059)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1396)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:681)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15481)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5059)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15481)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5059)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15481)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5059)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2377)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15481)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1982)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1200)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1398)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1118)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4525)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4946)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.jav
```

### Also...

- I have unsuccessfully been able to try the other possible solution mentioned in https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=42601, mentioned in post #2 and #13, because I haven't understood how and where I can use it in my code (I guess I'm in the same boat as the person who wrote #18).

Comment: If you successfully achieved then please share your code

Answer (score 38):

I think I just ran into this same problem and learned a few things by looking at the source for [DialogFragment](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.2.2_r1/android/support/v4/app/DialogFragment.java?av=f).

It looks like even though overriding onCreateDialog(...) is a valid way to create a custom dialog, it will result in the DialogFragment having a null View, just like the error message says. In most cases this is fine - the DialogFragment doesn't need a View to show a Dialog, but if you want to nest fragments further (like you do), this won't fly.

Considering that you want to interact with an AlertDialog.Builder, there is really no perfect solution that I can see, but you've got a few options:

1. Create the buttons in your dialog as part of the View (not using AlertDialog.Builder). You do this by overriding onCreateView *instead* of onCreateDialog. You should be able to get the functionality you mention by putting the buttons in their own fragment. We do something similar at my gig, and I very much prefer this method.
2. Implement your own type that inherits from Fragment and that mirrors the DialogFragment in every way except allowing what you need. This shouldn't be too scary as DialogFragment is only ~400 and is heavily commented. Could be fun.
3. Use a regular PagerAdapter instead of a FragmentPagerAdapter. This way it won't matter that your DialogFragment doesn't have a View.

Answer (score 22):

Use the

```
onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
```

instead of onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState). Don't create an alert dialog, use the inflater provided by the method, and build your view. It works for me.

Best regards!

Comment: this actually worked.  if you are overriding onCreateDialog to create dialog as me, this will save you.

Comment: I had the same issue with BottomSheetDialogFragment, using this method as opposed to setupDialog(Dialog dialog, int style) did the trick when I was trying to add a fragment on the bottom sheet itself.

Answer (score 9):

If you implement `onCreateDialog` to use `AlertDialog`, you will bump into `IllegalStateException: Fragment does not have a view` when accessing `getChildFragmentManager` or something equivalent.

To solve this issue, implement both `onCreateDialog` and `onCreateView`, where `onCreateView` return the view inflated in `onCreateDialog`.

```
class LocationPickerDialog : DialogFragment() {

    lateinit var customView: View

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return customView
    }

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreateDialog")
        // StackOverflowError
        // customView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_location_picker, null)
        customView = activity!!.layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_location_picker, null)

        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(context!!)
                .setView(customView)
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok) { _, _ ->
                    // do something
                }
                .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel) { _, _ ->
                    // do something
                }
        val dialog = builder.create()

        return dialog
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        // if onCreateView doesn't return a view 
        // java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment does not have a view
        mapFragment = childFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("map") as SupportMapFragment?
    }
}
```

https://code.luasoftware.com/tutorials/android/android-alertdialog-in-dialogfragment-fragment-does-not-have-a-view/

Comment: Thanks. Your suggestion enables me to handle a difficult corner case - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55066977/how-to-prevent-custom-dialogfragment-from-hiding-keyboard-when-being-shown

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Tommy Visic for writing a really good description it worked.

Posting the code which worked for me.

I have removed the `Dialog` building code from the `onCreateDialog` method infact removed `onCreateDialog` method and the dialog view which I have been implementing in the `Dialog's` custom view I have included it as a `View` in the `onCreateView` method and all the things started working.

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.login_sigup_screen, null, false);
    bind = ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    initViewPager();
    return view;
}
```

Faced one more problem with this implementation is:

When a `Activity` has `Toolbar/ActionBar` then it is also displayed into the `DialogFragment` to avoid that what is to be done is:
Implement `onViewCreated` method of `Fragment` and add below code

```
Dialog dialog = getDialog();
dialog.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
float dimAmount = 0.6f;
dialog.getWindow().setDimAmount(dimAmount);
```

This will remove the `Toolbar` from the `DialogFragment` and `Activity` will be displayed as it is.

Cheers

Thanks @Tommy

Regards
Zeus

Answer (score 0):

I ran into same issue and achieve the following solution :

```
class MyDialogFragment: DialogFragment {

  private lateinit var dialog: AlertDialog
  private lateinit var dialogView: View

  override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    // return the view inflated for your dialog fragment
    return dialogView
  }

  // this is called before onCreateView
  override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
    dialogView = LayoutInflater
            .from(ContextThemeWrapper(requireContext(), R.style.MyAlertDialogStyle))
            .inflate(R.layout.fragment_dialog, null, false)
    dialog = AlertDialog
            .Builder(requireContext())
            .setView(dialogView)
            .create()

    dialog.setOnShowListener {
        childFragmentManager
                  .beginTransaction()
                  .replace(R.id.container, MyNestedFragmentInsideTheDialog())
                  .commit()
        // retrieve dialog buttons if any to manage onClickListener yourself
        // dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE)
    }
  }

}
```

The idea is to inflate the dialog content yourself and to keep a reference on it so it can be returned into onCreateView and then used by the childfragmentManager ;-)

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use setOnShowListener method in onViewCreated

```java
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull @NotNull View view, @Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        getDialog().setOnShowListener(dialog -> {
            getDialog().findViewById(R.id.et_input).requestFocus();
            SoftKeyBoardUtil.showKeyBoard(getDialog().getWindow());
        });
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

you can make variable and put the condition between try and catch same that

```
  val comeFrom = try {
                args.comeFrom.toString()
            }catch (e:Exception){
                "0"
            }
```