# AppCompat-styled dialog containing a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-appcompat, android-dialog, appcompatdialog

I want an AppCompat-styled dialog - background, title, button position, button tint etc. - containing a Fragment.

With a custom `DialogFragment` `onCreateDialog()` can return an `AppCompatDialog`, then in `onCreateView()` a new layout can be inflated and `childFragmentManager` can be used to replace a placeholder view with the Fragment. But the resulting dialog is otherwise an empty box with no buttons. They can be manually added to the dialog's layout but they get no styling from AppCompat.

The same applies if you make the target Fragment extend `DialogFragment`.

To get AppCompat buttons you can use `AlertDialog.Builder`, and use `.setView()` to set the layout, but then I can't find a way to set the Fragment as the content. If you try `childFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace()` from `onCreateDialog()` then you get:

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment does not have a view
```

This seems to be because, even after using `builder.setView()` or `dialog.create()`  then `dialog.setView()`,  `onCreateView()` and `getView()` always return null.

The second answer here seems to cover this quite comprehensively but doesn't suggest a favourable solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21418952/2645845

If you override `onCreateView()` or `getView()` to return the View you inflated then you get:

```
 android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Window feature must be requested before adding content
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.throwFeatureRequestIfSubDecorInstalled(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1479)
```

Comment: Why not just use [AppCompatDialogFragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDialogFragment.html)?