# How to prevent custom DialogFragment from hiding keyboard when being shown

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-dialogfragment

There are 2 ways to create custom dialog via `DialogFragment`.

1. Overwrite `onCreateDialog` and return a dialog using `AlertDialog.Builder`.
2. Overwrite `onCreateView`.

We notice that, if we overwrite `onCreateDialog`, the previous shown soft keyboard will not be hidden.

However, if we overwrite `onCreateView`, **the previous shown soft keyboard will be hidden.**

### onCreateDialog will not hide soft keyboard

[image]

---

### onCreateView will hide soft keyboard

[image]

---

Hiding soft keyboard is not our desired behavior. We want the soft keyboard to remain same as it is.

However, we are not able to use `onCreateDialog` way, due to the limitation mentioned [ViewPager in DialogFragment - IllegalStateException: Fragment does not have a view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20303865/viewpager-in-dialogfragment-illegalstateexception-fragment-does-not-have-a-vi) . In nutshell, if you need `ViewPager` to work well in dialog, you cannot implement custom dialog using `onCreateDialog`.

If we use `onCreateView`, we can achieve everything desired, except "not hiding soft keyboard".

***Do you have any idea why overwrite `onCreateView` to create custom dialog, will hide the keyboard? How can we prevent such behavior?***

---

### Code

My dialog style is:

```
<style name="CustomDialog" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">false</item>
</style>
```

**ColorDialogFragment.java**:

```
public class ColorDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private ColorFragmentPagerAdapter colorFragmentPagerAdapter;

    public static ColorDialogFragment newInstance() {
        ColorDialogFragment colorDialogFragment = new ColorDialogFragment();
        // We provide custom style, because we need title.
        colorDialogFragment.setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.CustomDialog);
        return colorDialogFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        getDialog().getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    }

    private View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.color_dialog_fragment, container, false);

        this.tabLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        this.viewPager = view.findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        this.colorFragmentPagerAdapter = new ColorFragmentPagerAdapter(this.getChildFragmentManager());
        this.viewPager.setAdapter(this.colorFragmentPagerAdapter);
        this.tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(this.viewPager);

        return view;
    }

    // We overwrite onCreateView because ViewPager in DialogFragment, can hardly play well with
    // onCreateDialog + AlertDialog.Builder.
    //
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20303865/viewpager-in-dialogfragment-illegalstateexception-fragment-does-not-have-a-vi
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return onCreateView(inflater, container);
    }

    // We overwrite onCreateDialog, because we need title.
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
        dialog.setTitle(R.string.select_a_color);
        return dialog;
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh this is a mess, what if we hide the keyboard and turn it on again when this popup appears? :-/

Comment: @ManojPerumarath We want to avoid that because (1) It doesn't yield a good user experience. (2) It is difficult to achieve. Need to remember the focus location/ component of parent, and then restore back when dialog is closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After day of experiment, I found out a solution!

**Overwrite both `onCreateDialog` and `onCreateView`. Store view created at `onCreateDialog` in a member variable, and let `onCreateView` return that member variable.**

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51530917/72437

Here's the complete code.

```
public class ColorDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    private View view;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private ColorFragmentPagerAdapter colorFragmentPagerAdapter;

    public static ColorDialogFragment newInstance() {
        ColorDialogFragment colorDialogFragment = new ColorDialogFragment();
        return colorDialogFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        getDialog().getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);


        // TODO: Read from WeNoteOptions.
        final int position = 0;
        this.viewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
        updateButtonVisibility(position);
    }

    private View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.color_dialog_fragment, container, false);

        this.tabLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        this.viewPager = view.findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        this.colorFragmentPagerAdapter = new ColorFragmentPagerAdapter(this.getChildFragmentManager());
        this.viewPager.setAdapter(this.colorFragmentPagerAdapter);
        this.tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(this.viewPager);

        this.viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                updateButtonVisibility(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    private void updateButtonVisibility(int position) {
        if (position == 1) {
            ((AlertDialog)getDialog()).getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            ((AlertDialog)getDialog()).getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }

    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20303865/viewpager-in-dialogfragment-illegalstateexception-fragment-does-not-have-a-vi
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return this.view;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        this.view = onCreateView(layoutInflater, null);
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .setTitle(R.string.select_a_color)
                .setView(this.view)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.select_color, (dialogInterface, i) -> {

                });
        return alertDialogBuilder.create();
    }
}
```