# Tabs, ViewPager & Fragments with Scrollview in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I've implemented a FragmentActivity using TabHost, ViewPager and Fragments following this short tutorial [Tutorial to implement the use of TabHost in Android 2.2 + ViewPager and Fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17687717/tutorial-to-implement-the-use-of-tabhost-in-android-2-2-viewpager-and-fragment#) but Instead of a RelativeLayout in activity_main.xml I put a ScrollView but its not scrolling at all, how can I make it work?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you have enough content in the ScrollView for it to even need to scroll? As far as I know it doesn't scroll until you have enough content (e.g. views).

Furthermore, why not set up a RelativeLayout and then within it the ScrollView? You can then set the width and height of the ScrollView to fill the parent:

> android: layout_height="fill_parent"
>
> android: layout_width="fill_parent"

Hope this helps ;)

Comment: Thanks! I tried that but did not work. I solved my problem using a ScrollView as root on each fragment, every tab content has its own scroll and not the entire activity.

Comment: In the tutorial above, sample_fragment.xml uses a RelativeLayout, I changed it to ScrollView and set up a RelativeLayout within the ScrollView.

Comment: No problem, glad you found a solution :)

Answer (score 0):

TabHost is deprecated, switch to ViewPager, and you can put the scrollview inside the relativelayout as REG1 answer