# How to implement Android SwipeRefreshLayout on a ViewPager containing ListFragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-listfragment, swiperefreshlayout

I have a tabbed activity which contains a ListFragment in each tab ([Tabs with ListFragments image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9B3Id.png)). In the main layout I have implemented a SwipeRefreshLayout that performs a network task and syncs some databases which both fragments rely on.

I have found that I can scroll to the bottom of my ListFragment list but I am unable to scroll back to the top of the list without causing the SwipeRefreshLayout to refresh. Is it possible to fix my activity so that it only refreshes once I reach the top of the List, and how would this be implemented?

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17687717/tutorial-to-implement-the-use-of-tabhost-in-android-2-2-viewpager-and-fragment) tutorial to implement the ViewPager with Lists.

## My Code-

### Main XML Layout-

```xml
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/swipe_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TabHost
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0" />

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/viewpager"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

### MainActivity-

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements
        TabHost.OnTabChangeListener, ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener
{
    // Handles ViewPager
    private MyPageAdapter fPageAdapter;
    private ViewPager fViewPager;
    private SwipeRefreshLayout fSwipeRefreshLayout;

    // Handles Tabs
    private TabHost fTabHost;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        fViewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

        // Tab Initialisation
        initialiseTabHost();

        // Fragments and ViewPager Initialisation
        List<Fragment> fragments = getFragments();
        fPageAdapter = new MyPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);
        fViewPager.setAdapter(fPageAdapter);
        fViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(MainActivity.this);

        fSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout)findViewById(R.id.swipe_container);
        fSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(swipeRefreshListener);
    }

    /**
     *  Swipe Refresh Listener
     */
    private SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener swipeRefreshListener = new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh()
        {
            fSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

            /**
             * Calls Async Task to perform network
             * operation and update database.
             */
        }
    };


    /**
     *  Other Functions Removed
     */


    /** Fragment Construction */

    /**
     * @brief create a list of default fragments to display
     * @return List Fragments - containing default fragments
     */
    private List<Fragment> getFragments()
    {
        String[] numbers_text = new String[] { "one", "two", "three", "four",
                "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten", "eleven",
                "twelve", "thirteen", "fourteen", "fifteen" };

        String[] colours = new String[] { "RED", "BLACK", "BLUE", "WHITE", "GREEN", "BROWN",
                "GREY", "YELLOW", "PINK", "PURPLE", "ORANGE", "VIOLET", "INDIGO"};

        List<Fragment>fList = new ArrayList<Fragment>();

        MyListFragment f1 = MyListFragment.newInstance(numbers_text);
        MyListFragment f2 = MyListFragment.newInstance(colours);
        fList.add(f1);
        fList.add(f2);

        return fList;
    }
}
```

Comment: Put your SwipeToRefreshLayout in your ListFragment. It's the quick fix.

Comment: @AawazGyawali, that would mean that I would have to implement the same code in each individual fragment that I tab?

Comment: I realised that I could just extend a ListFragment with the functionality that I required and have other ListFragments extend that when required. I apologise for momentarily forgetting how Object Oriented Programming works. Thanks for the tip @AawazGyawali.